# VB.Net or C# to strip html but leave less than or greater than

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I have a string variable that contains the following html data:

`<p>
    <em><strong>This is some <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">rich </span>text. 3 < 5 is a valid statement. <br />
    </strong></em></p>`

I need to be able to strip out the html, but leave any less than or greater than signs in case the data contains mathematical equations (like the "3 < 5" portion of the string). I am not able to use 3rd party applications/tools due to some restrictions of our site, and would prefer to use anything that is in the .net framework version 3.5. I have tried the regular expressions that follow, but they do not handle the less than/ greater than symbols.

`<[^>]*>`
`<[^>]+>`
`<(.|\n)*?>` 
`\<[^\>]*\>`

I have also tried the code on [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619174622/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042501-1.shtml), but it also does not handle the less than / greater than symbols either.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the first person to suggest regex be shot?

Comment: Not sure I agree, in this particular case. Parsing HTML with regex is a Bad Idea (TM), but in this case he wants to remove all tags matching a regex. Parsing HTML in this case would also be annoying as you'd have to traverse the entire tree to concatenate your string. Unless parsing libraries can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all text matching this with ''

```
(<[^\s]+[^<>]*>)+
```

(I tested it on Rubular.com, but it should work for C# too.)

Apparently the code should be

```
RegexObj.Replace('<p> <em><strong>This is some <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">rich </span>text. 3 < 5 is a valid statement. <br /> </strong></em></p>', "")
```

Comment: Thank you David! That resolved my issue. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not working for texts like this: il saldo > 1000 

 

valore < 200 e valore_test > 500

Comment: I've tweaked it: it should now handle that case too